# Android TCP error failed to resolve host name from static library

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, android, tcp, https

I'm using ffmpeg on android and i have encountered and error, that does not occur when i'm using the library on my linux VM.
I'm using FFmpeg Static Builds, from [here](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).
I am using the stable 3.1.5 x86_64 build on the emulator and the linux VM..

The emulator i'm using is genymotion API 22 nexus 6p, linux vm is ubuntu 16.04.
The problem also occurs on my physical phone which is nexus 5 running cyanogenmod 6, API 22.

Android Log:

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.5-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-2) 20160904
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libebur128 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[tcp @ 0x4029cc0] Failed to resolve hostname r8---sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com: Name or service not known
https://r8---sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video/mp4&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&dur=338.175&ms=au&mt=1477750809&fexp=9446761&mv=m&itag=22&mm=31&mn=sn-ivuoxu-ua8l&key=yt6&id=o-ANbaVtkKQuOcWMW9UrYRp47rRSKKc-1d3AGaTRwYVS6z&expire=1477772565&pcm2cms=yes&ip=5.29.246.6&lmt=1470910909244041&ei=tbAUWJvkHsjIiwahzIu4AQ&pl=26&source=youtube&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2cms,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&initcwndbps=2532500&upn=jtb8x3K3rqs&signature=D1E8DF4167175F11BE67DE0141B459715047AFDD.69E5499B1345F3A7F2AB4B938F6C05055C3144AB: Input/output error
```

Here is the log from linux VM:

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.5-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-2) 20160904
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libebur128 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://r8---sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video/mp4&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&dur=338.175&ms=au&mt=1477750809&fexp=9446761&mv=m&itag=22&mm=31&mn=sn-ivuoxu-ua8l&key=yt6&id=o-ANbaVtkKQuOcWMW9UrYRp47rRSKKc-1d3AGaTRwYVS6z&expire=1477772565&pcm2cms=yes&ip=5.29.246.6&lmt=1470910909244041&ei=tbAUWJvkHsjIiwahzIu4AQ&pl=26&source=youtube&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2cms,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&initcwndbps=2532500&upn=jtb8x3K3rqs&signature=D1E8DF4167175F11BE67DE0141B459715047AFDD.69E5499B1345F3A7F2AB4B938F6C05055C3144AB':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-08-11 10:21:33
  Duration: 00:05:38.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 555 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 426 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-11 10:21:33
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-11 10:21:33
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
[ipod @ 0x5264580] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, ipod, to 'output.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-11 10:21:33
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    5241kB time=00:05:38.12 bitrate= 127.0kbits/s speed=35.4x    
video:0kB audio:5184kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.112068%
```

The command im using :

```
./ffmpeg -i 'https://r8---sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video/mp4&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&dur=338.175&ms=au&mt=1477750809&fexp=9446761&mv=m&itag=22&mm=31&mn=sn-ivuoxu-ua8l&key=yt6&id=o-ANbaVtkKQuOcWMW9UrYRp47rRSKKc-1d3AGaTRwYVS6z&expire=1477772565&pcm2cms=yes&ip=5.29.246.6&lmt=1470910909244041&ei=tbAUWJvkHsjIiwahzIu4AQ&pl=26&source=youtube&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2cms,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&initcwndbps=2532500&upn=jtb8x3K3rqs&signature=D1E8DF4167175F11BE67DE0141B459715047AFDD.69E5499B1345F3A7F2AB4B938F6C05055C3144AB' -vn -acodec copy output.m4a
```

My Question is does android make some kind of restriction on static libraries? What is causing the issue ? 
I have no problem pinging the host right after i try to run the command, and it working fine !

```
ping -c 4 r8---sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com
PING r8.sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com (213.57.23.19) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 213.57.23.19: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from 213.57.23.19: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from 213.57.23.19: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=23.1 ms
64 bytes from 213.57.23.19: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=27.1 ms

--- r8.sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.689/21.322/27.103/5.300 ms
```

Some observation that i have made from my testing :

- The problem is not with the internet, since i can ping the host right after without problem.
- The problem is not with the url, i have tried with this one and i'm getting the same error `https://video-cdn.buzzfeed.com/13800/mp4_640x640/1478210253`
- The library is working fine on the linux VM, but not on the android, this may be an error with the implemetation(most definatly not), packaging (maybe), or android itself.

### MAJOR EDIT :

I have just reread the readme file for the libraries and i noticed this:

```
 A limitation of statically linking glibc is the loss of DNS resolution. Installing
             nscd through your package manager will fix this or you can use
             "ffmpeg -i http://<ip address here>/" instead of "ffmpeg -i http://example.com/"
```

I gave found this function from c# , that might do what I need,   :[dns lookup msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My lazy guess is a quoting/escaping issue.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have tried without quotes,with single quotes, and with double quotes("),same error.Also there should have been an error in the url printed from the program which is not the case.

Comment: What happens when you `ping r8---sn-ivuoxu-ua8l.googlevideo.com`? That works on my (vanilla) Android 6.

Comment: @DanielB Please take a look at my edit

Comment: Have you actually tried to access the file on that host? I tried. It's 403ing me on authorisation. Though that doesn't explain why android seems to be unable to even look it up. Is the android device only using 'wifi' ? -- https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-October/023893.html also this has the same issue back in 2014?

Comment: Might it have something to do with permissions?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170926/application-specific-dns-problem -- more stuff indicating the static builds may have issues.

Comment: @djsmiley2k The url is always fine, as i generate it on the go, and **I mad sure* it's always available when i run the script. The problem might actually be witht the static build itself, i will try to complie ffmpeg on my own, and see if it works.

Comment: @BenN The file is accessed by root user with su, and the file has all permission (777)

Comment: " gave found this function from c#" - A C# function is useless if you have a C/C++/Java program.  `FFmpeg` isn't written in C#, and Android can't use C# code.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry for the confusion, it was late at night, and i wanted to say that i will test a prototype, if it works i will post full answer.